# Trying to retreive time_t equals to 1 sec. from tm equals Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970

Tags: c++, time, time-t

Why is forward conversion from `time_t`, equaled to 1, to `tm` valid, whereas backward is not?

```
#include <ctime>
#include <map>
using namespace std;
int main() {

    time_t timer = 1;
    tm *timerSt = gmtime(&timer);
    cout << asctime(timerSt) << endl;   //Thu Jan 01 00:00:01 1970
    timer = mktime(timerSt);
    cout <<"timer 0: "<< timer << endl; //timer 0: -1
}
```

Comment: `mktime` assumes local time, not UTC time; it's the inverse of `localtime`, not `gmtime`. Presumably, your time zone is ahead of UTC, so midnight 1970-1-1 local time is before 1970-1-1 UTC, and is not representable in `time_t`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, I'm in Ukraine. So how can I mend it? There must be appropriate function. Isn't it?

Comment: Some implementations offer [`mkgmtime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/mkgmtime-mkgmtime32-mkgmtime64) or [`timegm`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/timegm.3.html), but it's non-standard. See also [How to convert a UTC date & time to a `time_t` in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12353011)

Comment: That is much better: timer = _mkgmtime(timerSt); It is giving an anticipated 1.